# Prevent Buttons from size growing no matter the text

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have a layout which is devided into many parts.

My question is about the LinearLayout "container_center2" which contains a group of Buttons.

The Buttons size grows when the Button text is longer.

**Below the XML layout :**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/container_center1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/container_top">
    <TextView android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/tmr" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="?lightBackground" />
    <TextView android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/txt" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" style="?noBackground" />
    <WebView android:id="@id/webview"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fieldImageForms"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/blank"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/container_center2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:baselineAligned="false" android:weightSum="6.0" android:layout_below="@id/container_center1">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/container_joker" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="3.0" android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <Button android:id="@id/joker1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:text="@string/txt_joker1" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <Button android:id="@id/joker2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:text="@string/txt_joker2" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <Button android:id="@id/joker3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:text="@string/txt_joker3" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/container_buttons" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="5.0">
        <Button android:id="@id/btn1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@id/btn2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@id/btn3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@id/btn4" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:gravity="top|center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/container_ads" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@id/container_center2" />
```

**The screenshot from the application when the text in normal:**
[This what how i want the Buttons to be no matter the legnth of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxln7.jpg)

**The screenshot from the application when the text is bigger, which makes the buttons push the Ads container:**
[This is the case to prevent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VurXk.jpg)

This is the layout changes progrmatically for each button:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new 
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
layoutparams.setMargins(3, 3, 0, 3);
mBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
mBtn1.setTextSize(0, 18F);
mBtn1.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
mBtn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Handler);
mBtn1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

**Question :**  I want to Buttons change to remain same as in the first screenshot and prebting it from growing ever if the button text will not be totally displayed.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your buttons

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the height of the button increasing by changing the `layout_height` XML attribute to a specific `dp` size like `android:layout_height="32dp"`.

You can also restrict number of lines the text in a button can take up by using the `maxLines` XML attribute. For example `android:maxLines="1"`. You may also want to use that in combination with `android:ellipsize="end"` so that if the text doesn't fit it'll have `...` at the end. For example `Very long text displ...`

Comment: Many thank for your well explained answer, it solved the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and mark one of the answers as accepted so it's clear to others that your question doesn't need more answers.